# Problem with PHP "Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable "

Tags: php, variables, count

Im completely new to PHP, please dont judge me by code it is not of my doing Im just fixing someone elses poor code. I got a task in job to fix issue with `count()` function.

Theres variable called `$var` which has a result function `count()` with variable in it.

the problem is that I get error on this line

```
$has = count($var); // Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

Heres the snippet of the code:

```
if($l)
foreach($list[$key] as $k=>$v){
    $var = @$c->content->config['has'][$v['type']];
    $has = count($var);
    echo '<li class="',($k==$l-1?'last ':''),($has?'folder ':'file ' ),(isset($list[$v['url']])?'open ':''),'type_',($v['type']),'"><span onClick="tree_tog(this)"></span><a href="',site_url('panel/'.($has?'index':'edit').'/'.$v['lang'].'/'.$v['nid'],null,false),'">',character_limiter($v['name'],40),'</a>';
    if($v['type']!='root'&&isset($list[$v['url']]))
        pr($list,$v['url'],$c);
    
    echo '</li>';
}
```

How can I fix this error? Anyone? please!!

Comment: if you print $var which output have?

Comment: `$var` doesn't contain anything that can be counted. Not everything is countable; what output would you expect from e.g. `count('roses are red')`? You have `@` to hide error messages so it's very likely you have, well, an error :)

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) for the `count()` function.

In your code, you have,

```php
$has = count($var);
```

This means you are trying to count the elements of `$var` or more specifically, the object or literal that the `$var` variable refers to. Now, the count function can count elements of an array or any other object that is said to be [countable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php). Not everything is countable. For instance, if you have an integer variable `$price = 200;` then the variable does not *contain* any elements in it, rather it has a number. So, the count function cannot count (the elements of) `$price` variable. Although, you could measure the length of the variable but that would be different than counting.

Simply put, you can count elements of an array or an object that has its properties structured in a way so that they can be countable. Otherwise, `count()` will fail and show that warning.

Try printing out the variable and see if you can figure out what's in it. There are several ways to print/debug in PHP objects,

```php
print_r($var);
```

Or,

```php
var_dump($var);
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Ive printed the result but I dont know what to do with it. It gave me some information that arrays = 7